# Does order of inheritance between class and interface matter?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Will it make any difference whether we inherit the `class` first or `interface` in `C++`?

example:

```
class A : public IAbstract, public ClassB
{
};

class A : public ClassB, public IAbstract
{
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the object layout will be different. Functionally however, it's equivalent.

In the first case, the object layout will be something like this:

```
------
IAbstract members, including vptr
------
Class B members
------
```

And in the second case:

```
------
Class B members
------
IAbstract members, including vptr
------
```

Comment: can you please little bit elaborate?

Answer (score 9):

The [initialization order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order) of direct base classes (i.e. `ClassB` and `IAbstract`) will be different. It's determined by the declaration order in base class specifier list.

(emphasis mine)

> 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in **left-to-right order** as they appear in this class's base-specifier list

Comment: Actually I asked the difference between an `interface` and `class`. if we inherit class also the order will be from left to right

Comment: @GilsonPJ, C++ has no notion of an interface, only a class. It's just a convention to call a class with no member variables and only pure virtual functions an "interface".

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry for the word "interface" I used to call the abstract classes with this name. One of the coding standard used by our client is always inherit the "absract" classes first then only classes. So I would like to know it will make any difference apart from calling the base class.

Comment: @GilsonPJ, no need to apologize, I'm just pedantic about terminology. You should follow the convention, unless your constructor needs things to be initialized in a certain order.

Comment: @GilsonPJ The only difference I can think of is the initialization order and object layout as StoryTeller mentioned. Otherwise, I think it won't matter.